# FireBase OnChildAdded not called on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using OnChildAdded event for get all data from database on Android.

The first time and many time later, It works well.
But something, onChildAdded don't be call for old child anymore. 
Uninstall and install app again make it work again.

I checked permission and added event.
I don't know what's wrong and what have to do to fix it.

This code, I use for init

```
    prayersRef = database.child("prayers");

    Log.w(TAG, "FireBaseDatabaseManager");

    prayersListener = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
            Prayer prayer = dataSnapshot.getValue(Prayer.class);
            prayer.uid = dataSnapshot.getKey();
            Log.w(TAG, "onChildAdded:" + prayer.uid);

            if (delegate != null) {
                delegate.OnPrayerAdded(prayer);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
            Log.w(TAG, "onChildChanged:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.w(TAG, "onChildRemoved:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
            Log.w(TAG, "onChildMoved:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        }
    };
```

Then I add event in here

```
    Log.i(TAG, "Add Child Event Listener");
    prayersRef.addChildEventListener(prayersListener);
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: where are you adding listener? In which lifecycle method?

Comment: I add in onAuthStateChanged When user logged in.

Answer (score 0):

OnChildAdded event is used to refreshing data. Try to retrieve data using ListenerForSingleValueEvent :) then in onDataChange you can put all downloaded items in list :) like:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     List<Model> models = new ArrayList<>();
     for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
         Model model = snapshot.getValue(Model.class);
         models.add(model);
     }    
}
```

Comment: When you add a `ChildEventListener`, its `onChildAdded()` will be called for each existing child and after that whenever a new child is added.